# How to align dom-to-image capture of Leaflet map to map's bounds?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, leaflet

I'm working on a project in which i'm capturing map screenshot (using [dom-to-image library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image)) and sending it to an external API which is returning back some coordinates(x,y,w,h) after processing the sent image. These co-ordinates(rectangles) i'm trying to draw on leaflet.

*As the captured image size is bigger than width and height of captured area (don't know why)*, I need to do scaling the co-ordinates.

Now the problem is Leaflet rectangles are not drawing on accurate position which external API is returning.

However, I'm sure that the external API is returning correct coordinates(x,y,w,h) with respect to sent image's width & height.

**Something wrong i'm doing on scaling coordinates.**

Below is the code snippet i'm trying:

```
domtoimage.toPng(document.querySelector("#map"))
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var boundsOnly = map.getBounds(); 
        let topLeft = boundsOnly.getNorthWest();
        let topRight = boundsOnly.getNorthEast();
        let bottomLeft = boundsOnly.getSouthWest();
        let bottomRight = boundsOnly.getSouthEast();
                
        var currBBOXpoints = { x1y1: map.latLngToLayerPoint(topLeft), 
                            x2y2: map.latLngToLayerPoint(topRight),
                            x3y3: map.latLngToLayerPoint(bottomRight),
                            x4y4: map.latLngToLayerPoint(bottomLeft) };
                            
        var pW = currBBOXpoints.x2y2.x - currBBOXpoints.x1y1.x;
        var pH = currBBOXpoints.x3y3.y - currBBOXpoints.x1y1.y;
        
        currBBOXpoints.pW = pW; //calculated the width of captured area
        currBBOXpoints.pH = pH; //calculated the height of captured area
        
        var i = new Image();
        i.onload = function () { //calculating captured image's actual width, height

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/externalapi',
                data: JSON.stringify(dataUrl),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (resultData) {
                    resultData["iW"] = i.width; //captured image width 
                    resultData["iH"] = i.height; //captured image height
                    resultData["currBBOXpoints"] = currBBOXpoints; //captured area bounds
                    drawRects(resultData);
                    //NOTE: Captured image's width and height are bigger than width and height of captured area (don't know why)
                }
            });
    };
    i.src = dataUrl;
});

function drawRects(rectData) {

    var scale = Math.max(rectData.currBBOXpoints.pW / rectData['iW'], rectData.currBBOXpoints.pH / rectData['iH']);
    
    var shifted_x = rectData.currBBOXpoints.pW / 2 - rectData['iW'] / 2 * scale;
    var shifted_y = rectData.currBBOXpoints.pH / 2 - rectData['iH'] / 2 * scale;

    rectData.od.forEach(rc => {
        var modifiedX = Number(rc['x']) * scale + shifted_x;
        var modifiedY = Number(rc['y']) * scale + shifted_y; 
        var modifiedW = (modifiedX + rc['w'])
        var modifiedH = (modifiedY + rc['h'])


        let point3 = map.layerPointToLatLng(L.point(modifiedX, modifiedY));
        let point4 = map.layerPointToLatLng(L.point(modifiedW, modifiedH));
        
        var rectBounds = [[point3.lat, point3.lng], [point4.lat, point4.lng]];
        var boundingBox = L.rectangle(rectBounds, { color: "yellow", weight: 1, name: "rect", fillOpacity: 0.10 });
        
        map.addLayer(boundingBox);

    });
}
```

Comment: Use containerPointToLatLng instead of layerPointToLatLng, this is the newer convert function.

Comment: @FalkeDesign Thanks for informing me about the newer convert function. Do you mean I need to replace all the 'layerPointToLatLng' functions calling with the newer convert function? Or any specific one?

Comment: I would replace all of them in both direction. [containerPointToLatLng](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-containerpointtolatlng) and [latLngToContainerPoint](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-latlngtocontainerpoint). But I don't know if this fix your problem.

Comment: Can you create a example only with example Data (without the server request). So we can test around?

Comment: I've tried both direction (containerPointToLatLng and latLngToContainerPoint) as what you've suggested. But not resolved the issue. Ok I'm trying to create example snippet with sample Data. Thank you once again!

Comment: @FalkeDesign Please check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/1v4qpe3b/6/) I've tried to explain in the comments in this snippet.

Comment: You say «As the captured image size is bigger than width and height of captured area». What are those sizes exactly? How do those compare? How big is the "unexpected" margin?

Comment: I mean, I made a [demo using `dom-to-image`](https://plnkr.co/edit/vPkN7uEmG9Uehv1y), and the size of the capture is the same as the size of the map canvas.

Comment: In the JsFiddle i've mentioned the image size. (1744px x 854px). I will try to upload the source code in github, if this problem doesn't resolve today.

Comment: @IvanSanchez please check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SdZ4R0MTYa9HNUXg) and see the console. There are difference between captured Image size and map container. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why but when you set the scale to 0.9 after defining `x` and `y` it matches perfect.

```
var scale = Math.max(currBBOXpoints.pW / imagesize.width, currBBOXpoints.pH / imagesize.height);

var x = currBBOXpoints.pW / 2 - imagesize.width / 2 * scale;
var y = currBBOXpoints.pH / 2 - imagesize.height / 2 * scale;
scale = 0.9
```

Also you have to set in the fiddle the css width and height:

```
#mapWrapper{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 1744px;
  height: 854px;
}
```

Comment: It was the problem with [dom-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image) library which was changing the size of captured image. After using [leaflet-image.js](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image)  and  [containerPointToLatLng](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-containerpointtolatlng) and [latLngToContainerPoint](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-latlngtocontainerpoint) issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (which you successfully identified: the size of the capture is not the size of the map container), so let's fix the root problem instead.

It looks like `dom-to-image` aligns the top-left corner of the capture, but also takes into account the size of any [overflowing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) elements (such as partially-visible map tiles on the southeast corner) when calculating the size of the capture:

[image: capture comparison]

(This can be proven by playing a bit with the browser's [box model inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_the_box_model), comparing the position & size of the southeasternmost tile with the size of the capture)

Since the capture is aligned top-left, you can just clip the capture to the size of the map canvas.

You can use the [`width` and `height` options of `dom-to-image`](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#height-width) together with the [`getSize` method of `L.Map`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-getsize) to force clipping the captured image to the dimensions of the map canvas, e.g.:

```
    domtoimage.toPng(document.querySelector("#leaflet"), {
        width: map.getSize().x,
        height: map.getSize().y
    })
```

See a [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/7pgcYY1coEmDV8eC).

Comment: Thank you IvanSachez. I had tried the same approach by using map.getSize() But it's not working in my project. Captured image size is same as map.getSize() x and y, but image is cropping from the bottom. I don't know why it's happening with my actual project.

Comment: After removing some CSS codes from my webpage, [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#height-width) is working fine now.